# PHP RSA encryption

Tags: php, rsa, public-key-encryption

I have the following Public Key:

```
//Beginig of the PBK
30819f300d06092a864886f70d010101050003818d003081890281810095e15f182ec7b6e84786c0ee54e3bb72af0461e6fd859a3625f38dcd3fdec80dfcc51a44756ec7cd6c14b430d55670460c5143efadd1ade7380e890e9957d6e6b38f35412862cc955e04d1928f21c0d2f7bc48c3855276f0e7c1b45a558e3a013b969cbfaebca42b748e64bff787f86ec5f0adcd94428c4ab8ca6d2b710d785b0203010001
//End of the PBK
```

which is a PKCS#1 encoded public key within a X509 structure.
So my question is How can I -in PHP- extract the public Key from this X509 PKIX format to use it in the RSA encryption?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using [phpseclib, a pure PHP RSA implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/):

```
<?php
include('Crypt/RSA.php');

$cert = pack('H*', '30819f300d06092a864886f70d010101050003818d003081890281810095e15f182ec7b6e84786c0ee54e3bb72af0461e6fd859a3625f38dcd3fdec80dfcc51a44756ec7cd6c14b430d55670460c5143efadd1ade7380e890e9957d6e6b38f35412862cc955e04d1928f21c0d2f7bc48c3855276f0e7c1b45a558e3a013b969cbfaebca42b748e64bff787f86ec5f0adcd94428c4ab8ca6d2b710d785b0203010001');

$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
$rsa->loadKey($cert);
echo $rsa;
?>
```

Returns this:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCV4V8YLse26EeGwO5U47tyrwRh5v2FmjYl843N
P97IDfzFGkR1bsfNbBS0MNVWcEYMUUPvrdGt5zgOiQ6ZV9bms481QShizJVeBNGSjyHA0ve8SMOF
Unbw58G0WlWOOgE7lpy/rrykK3SOZL/3h/huxfCtzZRCjEq4ym0rcQ14WwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

What I think phpseclib is really doing here is base64_encode'ing the packed $cert and adding a header and a footer to it.  In what format do you want the key?  Do you want the exponent and the modulo in base-10 format or is the above sufficient?

Comment: Hello, Thank you so much for the answer, sorry If I did not read it in time, so yes I need to extract modulo and exponent from the key, can you show me how and thanks.

Comment: You could do `extract($rsa->getPublicKey(CRYPT_RSA_PUBLIC_FORMAT_RAW)); echo $e; echo $n;`